# Combining data from multiple $http calls

Tags: angularjs

I have 3 api endpoints

1. /getAccount which returns

`[{"id":"1", "name":"Bank 1", "starting_balance":"0.00"},{"id":"2", "name":"Bank 2", "starting_balance":"10.83"}]` into `$scope.acc`

2. /getExpense which returns

`[{"id":"1", "amount":"400.00"},{"id":"2", "amount":"500.00"}]` into `$scope.expense`

3. /getIncome which returns

`[{"id":"1", "amount":"1000.00"},{"id":"2", "amount":"1000.00"}]` into `$scope.income`

I don't know how to combine these three data. Here is my HTML code:

```
<tr>
   <td>Account Name</td>
   <td>Starting Balance</td>
   <td>Income</td>
   <td>Expense</td>
</tr>
<tr ng-repeat="a in acc">
   <td>{{a.name}}</td>
   <td>{{a.starting_balance}}</td>
   <td></td>
   <td></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: I like both ryanyuyu's and Sachila Ranawaka's answers! Can I select both?

Comment: If you find both answers useful, you can upvote both.  But you can only accept one answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are trying to make 3 AJAX calls and then combine all the results together.  It might be better just to aggregate this information in the API that you call instead of trying to fix this client-side.

But if you're stuck with the API and have to do this client-side, I suggest using [`$q.all`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#all) to combine the 3 separate promises (from the API calls) into a single post-processing function.

For example, in your controller code:

```
$q.all([api.getAccount(), api.getExpense(), api.getIncome()])
    .then(combineInformation);

function combineInformation(apiResults) {
    var accountInfo = apiResults[0]; //result of getAccount()
    var expenseInfo = apiResults[1]; //result of getExpense()
    var incomeInfo = apiResults[2];  //result of getIncome()

    var aggregateInfo = accountInfo.map(buildInfo);

    function buildInfo(account) {
        var info = {
            id: account.id,
            account: account
        };

        info.expense = expenseInfo.find(function (e) { return e.id === info.id; });
        info.income = incomeInfo.find(function (i) { return i.id === info.id; });
        return info;
    }
    $scope.arr = aggregateInfo;
}
```

[Demo on plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/9r92Id2zgh10myRrifC9?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

combine the arrays using map operator.

Demo

```js
angular.module('app',[])
.controller('ctrl',function($scope){
$scope.income = [{"id":"1", "amount":"1000.00"},{"id":"2", "amount":"1000.00"}]

$scope.expense = [{"id":"1", "amount":"400.00"},{"id":"2", "amount":"500.00"}]

$scope.acc = [{"id":"1", "name":"Bank 1", "starting_balance":"0.00"},{"id":"2", "name":"Bank 2", "starting_balance":"10.83"}] 

$scope.arr = $scope.acc.map((item) => {
    var exp = $scope.expense.find((ex) => ex.id === item.id)
    var inc = $scope.income.find((ins) => ins.id === item.id)
    return {
      acc : item,
      inc : inc,
      exp : exp
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
<table>
<tr>
   <td>Account Name</td>
   <td>Starting Balance</td>
   <td>Income</td>
   <td>Expense</td>
</tr>
<tr ng-repeat="a in arr">
   <td>{{a.acc.name}}</td>
   <td>{{a.acc.starting_balance}}</td>
   <td>{{a.inc.amount}}</td>
   <td>{{a.exp.amount}}</td>
</tr>

</table>
</div>
```

Comment: I like your answer. But since ryanyuyu's answer accurately address the promise issue, I choose his/her answer. Thanks for your help. Really appreciate it.